# How to capture promise return and use it in a variable

Tags: protractor

I'm using the following code to capture a value from an element and use that element in a sendKeys command later on in the code.

```
getPort = function(){
    $('#Window').element(by.id('Port')).getAttribute('value').then(function(text){
            console.log(text);
            return text;
        });
        };
var port = getPort();
```

I later on (in the same "it" block) try and call a sendKeys

```
$('#Window').element(by.id('LinkedIPAddress')).sendKeys('website:' +port);
```

However the sendKeys command always says the variable port is an undefined value, the console log from the function displays the correct information so I know it is capturing the correct info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `getPort()` return a *promise*:

```
getPort = function() {
    return $('#Window').element(by.id('Port')).getAttribute('value');
};
```

And resolve it when you need a real value:

```
getPort().then(function (port) {
    $('#Window').element(by.id('LinkedIPAddress')).sendKeys('website:' + port);
});
```

Comment: This got me to where I needed to be, since the sendKeys command is not pointing at a page with the getPort() return on it, I had to set a variable to capture the promise



`var port2 = getPort();`
`port2.then(function...`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`port` is undefined because you're only returning to the callback; not your method. You need one more `return`. This should work:

```
getPort = function(){
  return $('#Window').element(by.id('Port')).getAttribute('value').then(function(text){
    console.log(text);
    return text;
  });
};

var port = getPort();
```

@alecxe's answer is also good. Just depends on how you want to work it.